# How does one properly create a second view for a controller in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am quite new to Rails and have created a second controller to display a list of items without providing the edit and destroy options. (it is meant as the front end) I am now trying to create a show view for that particular listing but am not sure what steps take. Having created a second view file, I seem unable to access information in the model, receiving undefined variable errors. I am able to access them in the main index view for the controller so I expect there is either something in routing or the controller itself that I have to add.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Updated October 1, 2013 16:15PST

The second view called show.html.erb, just contains the following code to see if it will pull up the data:

```
<p><%= plant.botanical_name %></p>
```

The first view, called index.html.erb, contains this and it pulls the variables correctly:

```
<h1>Plant Display</h1>

<% @plants.each do |plant| %>

<div class="listingItem">
    <div class="showThumbnail">
        <%= link_to display_show_path do %>
            <%= image_tag plant.photo.url(:medium) %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
    <div class="listingItemInformation">
            <p><%= plant.botanical_name %></p>
            <p><%= plant.family %></p>
            <p><%= plant.common_name %></p>
    </div>

</div>
<div class="clear">
</div>
<% end %>
```

The controller just has this:

```
class DisplayController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @plants = Plant.order(:botanical_name)
  end
end
```

Also, in terms of versions: Rails 4.0.0.rc1 and Ruby 1.9.3p392

Comment: You should post your controller code, so we can make specific suggestions.

Comment: Yes, possibly your views code too please. Also make sure to include the directory your files are in.

Comment: What are the names of your view files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `plant` variable in the `index` view is actually an argument to the iteration block. When you write this:

it iterates over all the plants in `@plants`, and on each iteration `plant` is assigned to a plant. `@plants` itself is defined in the `index` controller method.

Your `show` view doesn't work because it uses `plant` but does not define it anywhere. Since you only want to show a single plant, what you want to do is to create a `@plant` variable in the `show` controller method and use it in the code instead of `plant`. So your controller should look something like this(didn't test it):

```
class DisplayController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @plants = Plant.order(:botanical_name)
  end

  def show
    @plant = Plant.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

and your view:

```
<p><%= @plant.botanical_name %></p>
```

Also, in the `index` view, you will want to change

```
<%= link_to display_show_path do %>
```

to

```
<%= link_to display_show_path(plant) do %>
```

so it will link to the currently iterated plant.

Comment: Thanks for your help Idan - Having re-compared the controller for the original model scaffold the assignment was happening in the before_action area which I completely missed. I am not quite out of the woods yet as I am now receiving a "Couldn't find Plant without an ID" error for the controller line @plant = Plant.find(params[:id]) but I'll do some more digging there.

Comment: If everything is configured correctly, when you click on the picture-link in the `index` view of `display` - lets say on the one of the plant with id=1 - the URL should end with `/display/1`. The `1` in the end is the id, and Rails will place it in `params[:id]`. The error you get indicates that something went wrong and the id was not placed in `params[:id]`. That means that either your routing configuration is wrong or the link creation code in the `index` view is wrong.

Comment: I must have missed something in the link creation code. At the moment, `<%= link_to display_show_path(plant) do %>` is creating the urls with a period instead of slash ie. http://localhost:3000/display/show.5
This is what I have in routes.rb
    `PlantDB::Application.routes.draw do
  get "display/show"
  get "display/index"
  get 'display/:id', to: 'display#show'
  resources :plants
  root 'display#index', as: 'display'
end`

Comment: You are creating two routes to the `show` method: `get "display/show"` - which does not accept an id(unless it's as a regular parameter) - and `get 'display/:id', to: 'display#show'` - which accepts an id as part of the path. My route-fu is a bit rusty, but I believe that due to the way you declared them they get different helpers. You can run `rake routes` from the command line to view all the routing helpers(minus the `_url`\`_path` suffix). At any rate, I think you can and should remove(or comment out) `do get "display/show"`, since you always need an `id` to show a plant.

Comment: Thank you again Idan. I ultimately switched to the `resources :display` option in the routing file and everything is working correctly now.